# Como convertir dropdownlist a texto en asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, html5, asp.net, dropdownlist

tengo un problema a la hora de convertir un dropdownlist  tengo solamente dos registros,
pongo mi codigo del formulario para que se entienda

```
<label for="exampleInpuntPassword">Condicion de Uso:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Propietario</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Alquilado</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

como se podra ver, yo no tengo mis registros en una Base de datos, pero quiero guardar estos registros en una, tengo otros atributos que no tengo problemas para guardar por que son Texbox.

--asi lo estaba colocando pero creo que esta mal

```
 oUbicacionesBLL.TipoRegistro = DropDownList2.Text;
```

--este si me funciona bien por que es un Texbox

```
   oUbicacionesBLL.NumeroGarantia = TxtNumG.Text;
```

Soy nuevo en Asp.net cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida

Comment: probaste con alguna de las otra propiedades del dropdown? como selectedtext?

Comment: @gbianchi Si, probe con SelectedItem, Value y nada

Comment: Ojo en tu ejemplo es dropdown3... no 2

Comment: @gbianchi si es que quiero agregar 3 dropdown por eso el codigo varia en sus nombres pero el problema es el mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo, por si alguien tiene la misma duda que yo tuve

```
oUbicacionesBLL.TipoRegistro = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
```